# PHP Uploading issue in wordpress, Getting Error 0 but image is not uploaded to my folder

Tags: php, file-upload

PHP Uploading issue in wordpress plugin, Getting Error 0 but the image was not uploaded to my folder. When I print out $_FILES I get

```
Array
(
    [resume] => Array
        (
            [name] => ace PLACEMENTS big-.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpMOwvKP
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 155773
        )
)
```

I'm using this code in my wp-job manager plugin -> job-application-email.php file.

html coding is:

```
<form action="" class="wppb-user-forms wppb-register-user" id="wppb-register-user" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ul>
        <li id="wppb-form-element-2" class="wppb-form-field wppb-default-username">
        <label for="name">Name<span title="This field is required" class="wppb-required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="name" maxlength="70" name="name" class="text-input default_field_username" required ></li>


        <li id="wppb-form-element-7" class="wppb-form-field wppb-default-website">

        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="phone" maxlength="70" name="phone" class="text-input default_field_website" required>
            <span class="wppb-description-delimiter">phone number</span></li>

        <li id="wppb-form-element-8" class="wppb-form-field wppb-default-e-mail">
        <label for="email">E-mail<span title="This field is required" class="wppb-required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" id="email" maxlength="70" name="email" class="text-input default_field_email" placeholder="Email" required></li>

        <li id="wppb-form-element-15" class="wppb-form-field wppb-default-nickname">
        <label for="nickname">Resume</label>
        <input type="file" name="resume">
        <span class="wppb-description-delimiter">qualification</span></li></ul>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">

        </form>
```

php coding is:

```
<?php 
$tmp = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];

$extension = explode(".", $_FILES['resume']['name']);
$everything = count($extension);

$ext = $extension[$everything - 1];

$newName = uniqid().time().".".$ext;
$curl = get_site_url()."/uploads";

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $curl."/".$newName))
{
    echo "successfully uploaded";
}
else {

echo "not uploaded";
}


?>
```

Comment: I believe you have permission to write inside the `/uploads` folder

Comment: ya I have folder permission to 777

Comment: What is inside your `wp_options` table for the coloumn "upload_path" ??

Comment: you should never use 777 in any case. 755 is better.

Comment: no it was not filled @sulthan allaudeen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using wordpress, I found this code from one of a wordpress page

the code is as follows:

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['resume'];

    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

    if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        //var_dump( $movefile); 
        //If you want to see details of your uploaded file uncomment the above line
    } else {
        /**
         * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
         * @see _wp_handle_upload() in wp-admin/includes/file.php
         */
        echo $movefile['error'];
    }
```

do not remove this "$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );" from above code, as it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a Self Debug Way**

There are mainly 2 reason for this error. At this time you shall look the following steps to fix it by yourself.

1. Make sure that you have enough permission to upload the image for your folder `/uploads`

Note : You can have 755 permission

2. Make sure that the table `wp_options` has the value for `upload_path` as `wp-content/uploads` in it. (If not update it)

Note : You can also update it at `Settings>Media`

Comment: no it was not still uploading after I put wp-content/uploads in wp_options table

Comment: Just for instance you can update it to `wp-content/uploads' to `wp-content/uploads/' ? (Just adding a slash after)

Comment: no still not uploading after adding / after uploads

Comment: Can you see the change inside `Settings>Media` ?

Comment: setting media has no changes.
it just has details about thumbnails and a checked check box of  "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" in it.
it does not have anything about folders

Comment: in which folder can I find it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80670/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-syed-mohamed-umar).

Comment: You can find it inside your root folder itself